# EditText validation not working as expected

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have developed android application and in there I have front end validation to a EditText field where its accept only three alpha and 4 digits.
It is tested in staging environment and front end validation is working perfectly (We don’t have back end validation). But after some time when we check
On our live database. We found some data with only digits relevant to above mentioned field.  It seems somehow validation will not effect in some device
And we have received data with only digits. Is it possible or what can be the reason that we received invalid data.

```
// Check for id is valid format like "ABC1234".
    String alphaLen = getResources().getString(R.string.rokaIdAlphaLen);
    String numLen = getResources().getString(R.string.rokaIdNumericLen);

    if (rokaId.length() > 0 && !Validate.validateRokaId(rokaId, alphaLen, numLen)) {
        etRokaid.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_format));
        focusView = etRokaid;
        cancel = true;
    }

public static boolean validateRokaId(String params, String alphaLen, String numLen) {


    boolean success = false;
    int alphaLength = 0;
    int numericLength = 0;

    alphaLength = Integer.parseInt(alphaLen.trim());
    numericLength = Integer.parseInt(numLen.trim());

    if (params.length() == alphaLength + numericLength) {
        if (params.substring(0, alphaLength).matches("[a-zA-Z]*")) {
            if (params.substring(alphaLength, alphaLength+numericLength).matches("[0-9]*")) {
                success = true;
            } else {
                success = false;
            }
        } else {
            success = false;
        }
    } else {
        success = false;
    }



    return success;
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: You _always_ need to validate both client and server side.  In the worst case scenario, some malicious user has hacked your app.  Best case, there are some use cases which can skirt your Android validation.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: added validation logic

Comment: @abc123 sir see my answer I was tested this in my studio and it perfectly working. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set Edit Text property **android:digits** in XML file for more security so no other special character to be inserted by the user even if you checked in validation.

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
```

Now for your format which is 3 character and 4 digit we create a Regex expression. You can create your own Regex Expression and test it from [this site](http://regexr.com/). I create this Regex from this site:

> [A-Z]{3}\d{4}

```
public final static Pattern NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$");
```

Now just match this pattern.

```
if (NAME_PATTERN.matcher(edtText.getText().toString().trim()).matches())
{
   // Write your logic if pattern match
}
else
{
   // Write your logic if pattern not match
}
```